# Finding MAX value of data type Varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Firstly I have a table `tblSample` with `ID` as column of datatype `INT`. To auto generate ID for every transaction, I created a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @Id INT

SELECT @Id = MAX(Id) 
FROM tblSample 

IF @Id IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT 0 as Id
END
ELSE 
    SELECT MAX(Id) as ID FROM tblSample
```

Here as you observe if `ID` has no rows `MAX(Id)=0` then return 0 or else return MAX(ID) value so that next insertion will be greater than max(ID).

That's fine but now I had column `ID` with datatype `VARCHAR` I have to do similar operation how can I that?

Comment: Let me explain you clearly for ex there is a Column named 'X' and user enters x value as 2 so that 2 rows with some columns will be displayed to user and user enters data when he click on submit those two rows should be assigned with same ID

Comment: Same logic should work for VARCHAR type as well. What's the issue with the above code ??

Comment: yeah worked I was confused btw MAX(varchar) and VARCHAR(max)...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine so it should work with VARCHAR also but my suggestion is to use storage variable also with same datatype so it won't get conflicted anywhere in the operation:

```
DECLARE @Id VARCHAR(10)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, will edit accordingly but I left that for default size. Really useful

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `MAX(CAST(varcharcolumn AS Int))`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Id INT
SELECT @Id=MAX(Id) FROM tblSample 
IF @Id IS NULL
BEGIN
 SELECT 'Your_VarCharValue' + CAST(0 AS VARCHAR) as Id
END
ELSE 
 SELECT 'Your_VarCharValue' + CAST(MAX(Id) AS VARCHAR) as ID FROM tblSample
```